# Where to download scrlayer-scrpage.sty?

Tags: packages, installing, scrlayer-scrpage

How to download the `scrlayer-scrpage.sty`? I don't find it anywhere.

I've tried to download on CTAN website but it doesn't give the .sty file. When I try to compile I get this error:

```
\aclabelfont undefined. \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}
File `scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found. \clearscrheadings
```

Comment: Use the package maintenance function of your distribution like MiKTeX or TeX Live.

Comment: It's a component of  `koma-script` and is part of standard distributions.

Comment: When you try to compile [what](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 1):

The error message about undefined `\aclabelfont` is independent from package [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage). I do not known, which package needs it but redefines it instead of defining it ([`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym), e.g., would need but also define it). Maybe you are using a not well defined template.

Nevertheless, as you can see from the [CTAN Catalogue entry of `scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) the package is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. You should not try to download and install `scrlayer-scrpage.sty` without a complete KOMA-Script installation, because the package depends on other parts of KOMA-Script, e.g., package `scrkbase`, `scrbase`, `scrlayer`.

The link above also documents that MiKTeX and TeX Live knows KOMA-Script as package `koma-script`. So you can and should simply use the package manager of your TeX distribution to install it. Experienced users can also use [KOMA's package repositories](http://www.komascript.de/current) to install a current pre-release of KOMA-Script or to download a TDS-archive. The TDS-archive of the current official release is also [available from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script.tds.zip).

Answer (score 0):

It is in package `koma-script`. If you do cannot obtain `koma-script` via your TeX package manager, you can download it from CTAN.

EDIT: The first comment underneath here actually has the correct answer. CTAN has the koma-script.tds.zip archive, which has what you need. Oddly, the *.sty file was not in what I downloaded earlier (supposedly the whole bundle).

Comment: `scrlayer-scrpage` depends on other KOMA-Script packages. And you need more than only one `.dtx` to create `scrlayer-scrpage.sty`. So installation from the `.dtx` is not recommended for average users. Recommended is the installation via the package manager of the TeX distribution. As alternative use the TDS-package either from CTAN or from [KOMA's package repositories](http://www.komascript.de/current). But this alternative is for experienced users only.