# Latex Error: File `scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I have a Latex form for my PhD thesis presentation. When I run it, the latex shows this error: Latex Error: File `scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found. I was wondering if someone could help me about my problem.  This is something written in my Latex:

‎

```
\documentclass[‎
‎11pt‎, % ‎The default document font size‎, ‎options‎: ‎10pt‎, ‎11pt‎, ‎12pt‎
%oneside, % ‎Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default‎, ‎uncomment to switch to one side‎
‎english‎, % ‎ngerman for German‎
‎singlespacing‎, % ‎Single line spacing‎, ‎alternatives‎: ‎onehalfspacing or doublespacing‎
%draft, % ‎Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures‎, ‎no links‎, ‎overfull hboxes indicated)‎
%nolistspacing, % ‎If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing‎, ‎uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single‎
%liststotoc, % ‎Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents‎
%toctotoc, % ‎Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents‎
%parskip, % ‎Uncomment to add space between paragraphs‎
%nohyperref, % ‎Uncomment to not load the hyperref package‎
‎headsepline‎, % ‎Uncomment to get a line under the header‎
%chapterinoneline, % ‎Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line‎
%consistentlayout, % ‎Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration‎, ‎abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout‎
‎]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure‎

‎\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters‎
‎\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters‎

‎\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default‎

‎\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)‎

‎\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography‎

‎\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  MARGIN SETTINGS‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\geometry{‎
‎   paper=a4paper‎, % ‎Change to letterpaper for US letter‎
‎   inner=2.5cm‎, % ‎Inner margin‎
‎   outer=3.8cm‎, % ‎Outer margin‎
‎   bindingoffset=.5cm‎, % ‎Binding offset‎
‎   top=1.5cm‎, % ‎Top margin‎
‎   bottom=1.5cm‎, % ‎Bottom margin‎
    %showframe, % ‎Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page‎
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  THESIS INFORMATION‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\thesistitle{Thesis Title} % Your thesis title‎, ‎this is used in the title and abstract‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \ttitle‎
‎\supervisor{Dr‎. ‎James \textsc{Smith}} % Your supervisor's name‎, ‎this is used in the title page‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \supname‎
‎\examiner{} % Your examiner's name‎, ‎this is not currently used anywhere in the template‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \examname‎
‎\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name‎, ‎this is used in the title page and abstract‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \degreename‎
‎\author{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name‎, ‎this is used in the title page and abstract‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \authorname‎
‎\addresses{} % Your address‎, ‎this is not currently used anywhere in the template‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \addressname‎

‎\subject{Biological Sciences} % Your subject area‎, ‎this is not currently used anywhere in the template‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \subjectname‎
‎\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis‎, ‎this is not currently used anywhere in the template‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \keywordnames‎
‎\university{\href{http://www.university.com}{University Name}} % Your university's name and URL‎, ‎this is used in the title page and abstract‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \univname‎
‎\department{\href{http://department.university.com}{Department or School Name}} % Your department's name and URL‎, ‎this is used in the title page and abstract‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \deptname‎
‎\group{\href{http://researchgroup.university.com}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL‎, ‎this is used in the title page‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \groupname‎
‎\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL‎, ‎this is used in the title page and abstract‎, ‎print it elsewhere with \facname‎

‎\AtBeginDocument{‎
‎\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title‎
‎\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name‎
‎\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords‎
}

‎\begin{document}‎

‎\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i‎, ‎ii‎, ‎iii‎, ‎iv...) for the pre-content pages‎

‎\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  TITLE PAGE‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{titlepage}‎
‎\begin{center}‎

‎\vspace*{.06\textheight}‎
‎{\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{1.5cm} % University name‎
‎\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type‎

‎\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line‎
‎{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title‎
‎\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line‎
 
‎\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}‎
‎\begin{flushleft} \large‎
‎\emph{Author:}\\‎
‎\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authorname} % Author name‎ - ‎remove the \href bracket to remove the link‎
‎\end{flushleft}‎
‎\end{minipage}‎
‎\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}‎
‎\begin{flushright} \large‎
‎\emph{Supervisor:} \\‎
‎\href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name‎ - ‎remove the \href bracket to remove the link‎  
‎\end{flushright}‎
‎\end{minipage}\\[3cm]‎
 
‎\vfill‎

‎\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text‎
‎\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]‎
‎\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name‎
 
‎\vfill‎

‎{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date‎
‎%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo‎ - ‎uncomment to place it‎
 
‎\vfill‎
‎\end{center}‎
‎\end{titlepage}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  DECLARATION PAGE‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{declaration}‎
‎\addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents‎
‎\noindent I‎, ‎\authorname‎, ‎declare that this thesis titled‎, ‎\enquote{\ttitle} and the work presented in it are my own‎. ‎I confirm that‎:

‎\begin{itemize}‎ 
‎\item This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University‎.
‎\item Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution‎, ‎this has been clearly stated‎.
‎\item Where I have consulted the published work of others‎, ‎this is always clearly attributed‎.
‎\item Where I have quoted from the work of others‎, ‎the source is always given‎. ‎With the exception of such quotations‎, ‎this thesis is entirely my own work‎.
‎\item I have acknowledged all main sources of help‎.
‎\item Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others‎, ‎I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\‎
‎\end{itemize}‎
 
‎\noindent Signed:\\‎
‎\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature‎
 
‎\noindent Date:\\‎
‎\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date‎
‎\end{declaration}‎

‎\cleardoublepage‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  QUOTATION PAGE‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\vspace*{0.2\textheight}‎

‎\noindent\enquote{\itshape Thanks to my solid academic training‎, ‎today I can write hundreds of words on virtually any topic without possessing a shred of information‎, ‎which is how I got a good job in journalism.}\bigbreak‎

‎\hfill Dave Barry‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  ABSTRACT PAGE‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{abstract}‎
‎\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents‎
‎The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page)‎. ‎The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots‎
‎\end{abstract}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{acknowledgements}‎
‎\addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents‎
‎The acknowledgments and the people to thank go here‎, ‎don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots‎
‎\end{acknowledgements}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents‎

‎\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures‎

‎\listoftables % Prints the list of tables‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  ABBREVIATIONS‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)‎

‎\textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere\\‎
‎\textbf{WSF} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or\\‎

‎\end{abbreviations}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  PHYSICAL CONSTANTS/OTHER DEFINITIONS‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{constants}{lr@{${}={}$}l} % The list of physical constants is a three column table‎

% ‎The \SI{}{} command is provided by the siunitx package‎, ‎see its documentation for instructions on how to use it‎

‎Speed of Light & $c_{0}$ & \SI{2.99792458e8}{\meter\per\second} (exact)\\‎
‎%Constant Name & $Symbol$ & $Constant Value$ with units\\‎

‎\end{constants}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  SYMBOLS‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\begin{symbols}{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)‎

‎$a$ & distance & \si{\meter} \\‎
‎$P$ & power & \si{\watt} (\si{\joule\per\second}) \\‎
‎%Symbol & Name & Unit \\‎

‎\addlinespace % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek‎

‎$\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\‎

‎\end{symbols}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  DEDICATION‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots}‎ 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  THESIS CONTENT‎ - ‎CHAPTERS‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering‎

‎\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the‎ ‎"thesis"‎ ‎style‎

% ‎Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder‎
% ‎Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters‎

‎\include{Chapters/Chapter1}‎
‎%\include{Chapters/Chapter2}‎ 
‎%\include{Chapters/Chapter3}‎
‎%\include{Chapters/Chapter4}‎ 
‎%\include{Chapters/Chapter5}‎ 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  THESIS CONTENT‎ - ‎APPENDICES‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following‎ ‎"chapters"‎ ‎are Appendices‎

% ‎Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder‎
% ‎Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices‎

‎\include{Appendices/AppendixA}‎
‎%\include{Appendices/AppendixB}‎
‎%\include{Appendices/AppendixC}‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‎%  BIBLIOGRAPHY‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]‎

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: How did you install LaTeX?

Comment: is your tex system a current system?

Comment: @JosephWright I downloaded the LaTeX from a cite and installed it.

Comment: @JosephWright I downloaded the LaTeX from a cite and installed it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what do you mean by current system? It is 2013 Version

Comment: we have 2021, so if you are using a version from 2013 it is certainly not current.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358176/where-to-download-scrlayer-scrpage-sty

Comment: As I do not have your "MastersDoctoralThesis" file I cannot say which package are loaded by the file and cannot reproduce your problem. However, have you tried loading the package via \usepackge{scrlayer-scrpage}? It looks to me that you have not loaded the package.

Comment: @Manuel The error refers to "‎\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}‎". How can I load the package?

Comment: The `\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}` is loaded by the class. You do not have to load it again. Perhaps the file `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` is also corrupted. Download from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There an "invisible" character for the TeX editor (using TeXstudio) all over the code that prevents its correct compilation.

I opened the tex file with `notepad++ > View >Show Symbol > Show All Characters`

to see for example

`â€Ž\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliographyâ€Ž`

The first `â€ž` is a  UTF-8 character that should not be there!

From https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

`U+201E     0x84    „   â€ž     %E2 %80 %9E`

After cleaning the file (again with notepad++) it compiles without errors.

[image: z]

This is the cleaned code

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
       paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
       inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
       outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
       bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
       top=1.5cm, % Top margin
       bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Thesis Title (file cleaned)} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{Biological Sciences} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{\href{http://www.university.com}{University Name}} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{\href{http://department.university.com}{Department or School Name}} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{\href{http://researchgroup.university.com}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
    \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        
        \vspace*{.06\textheight}
        {\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{1.5cm} % University name
        \textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type
        
        \HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
        {\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
        \HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line
        
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft} \large
                \emph{Author:}\\
                \href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authorname} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
                \end{flushleft}
            \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright} \large
                \emph{Supervisor:} \\
                \href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
                \end{flushright}
            \end{minipage}\\[3cm]
        
        \vfill
        
        \large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
        \textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
        \groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name
        
        \vfill
        
        {\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
        %\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it
        
        \vfill
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  DECLARATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{declaration}
    \addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents
    \noindent I, \authorname, declare that this thesis titled, \enquote{\ttitle} and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:
    
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.
        \item Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.
        \item Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.
        \item Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
        \item I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
        \item Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\
        \end{itemize}
    
    \noindent Signed:\\
    \rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature
    
    \noindent Date:\\
    \rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
    \end{declaration}

\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace*{0.2\textheight}

\noindent\enquote{\itshape Thanks to my solid academic training, today I can write hundreds of words on virtually any topic without possessing a shred of information, which is how I got a good job in journalism.}\bigbreak

\hfill Dave Barry

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
    \addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents
    The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
    \end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{acknowledgements}
    \addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
    The acknowledgments and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots
    \end{acknowledgements}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\listoftables % Prints the list of tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)
    
    \textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere\\
    \textbf{WSF} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or\\
    
    \end{abbreviations}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  PHYSICAL CONSTANTS/OTHER DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{constants}{lr@{${}={}$}l} % The list of physical constants is a three column table
    
    % The \SI{}{} command is provided by the siunitx package, see its documentation for instructions on how to use it
    
    Speed of Light & $c_{0}$ & \SI{2.99792458e8}{\meter\per\second} (exact)\\
    %Constant Name & $Symbol$ & $Constant Value$ with units\\
    
    \end{constants}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{symbols}{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)
    
    $a$ & distance & \si{\meter} \\
    $P$ & power & \si{\watt} (\si{\joule\per\second}) \\
    %Symbol & Name & Unit \\
    
    \addlinespace % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek
    
    $\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\
    
    \end{symbols}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
%\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
%\include{Chapters/Chapter5} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixC}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

**Update**

I can only reproduce the error `! LaTeX Error: File scrlayer-scrpagex.sty not found.` by changing the line 278 of the   file `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`  from
`\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}` to, for example, `\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpagex}`.

My guess is the file you are using is somehow corrupted. Get a new one from `https://www.latextemplates.com/templates/theses/1/thesis_1.zip`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used the cleaned code but unfortunately it doesn't work yet because of "Latex Error: File `scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found".

Comment: @M.Ramana Please see the updated thoughts in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works now without any problem. Thanks a lot.